# success is false from server

Tags: java, android

Hi in the below code success is false from server while parsing json data.status code is 200 and created.

`Login Modules` class contains list of strings and `GetModuleList` contains a list of strings but in the modules is an array it contains a list of objects

**LoginModules.java:**

```
public class LoginModules {

@SerializedName("success")
private String success;

@SerializedName("result")
private List<GetLoginModuleList> result;

public List<GetLoginModuleList> getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(List<GetLoginModuleList> result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public String getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(String success) {
    this.success = success;
}
```

}

**GetLoginModuleList.java:**

```
  public class GetLoginModuleList {

            @SerializedName("session")
            @Expose
            private String session;
            @SerializedName("userid")
            @Expose
            private String userid;
            @SerializedName("vtiger_version")
            @Expose
            private String vtiger_version;

            @SerializedName("modules")
            @Expose
            private List<Modules> modules;

            public List<Modules> getModules() {
                return modules;
            }

            public void setModules(List<Modules> modules) {
                this.modules = modules;
            }

            public String getSession() {
                return session;
            }

            public void setSession(String session) {
                this.session = session;
            }

            public String getUserid() {
                return userid;
            }

            public void setUserid(String userid) {
                this.userid = userid;
            }

            public String getVtiger_version() {
                return vtiger_version;
            }

            public void setVtiger_version(String vtiger_version) {
                this.vtiger_version = vtiger_version;
            }

            public String getMobile_module_version() {
                return mobile_module_version;
            }

            public void setMobile_module_version(String mobile_module_version) {
                this.mobile_module_version = mobile_module_version;
            }

            @SerializedName("mobile_module_version")
            @Expose
            private String mobile_module_version;


        }
```

**GetLoginModulesList.java:**

```
public class GetLoginModuleList {


@SerializedName("login")
private GetLoginList login;

public GetLoginList getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(GetLoginList login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public List<Modules> getModules() {
    return modules;
}

public void setModules(List<Modules> modules) {
    this.modules = modules;
}

@SerializedName("modules")
private List<Modules> modules;
```

}

Modules.java:

```
public class Modules {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("isEntity")
    @Expose
    private String isEntity;

    @SerializedName("label")
    @Expose
    private String label;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIsEntity() {
        return isEntity;
    }

    public void setIsEntity(String isEntity) {
        this.isEntity = isEntity;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getSingular() {
        return singular;
    }

    public void setSingular(String singular) {
        this.singular = singular;
    }

    @SerializedName("singular")
    @Expose
    private String singular;
}
```

**Json response:**

```
{
"success": true,
"result": {
    "login": {
        "userid": "1",
        "session": "fa000f0a6c5a414e62dcc4cbf99175d6",
        "vtiger_version": "5.2.0",
        "mobile_module_version": "1.2.1"
    },
    "modules": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Calendar",
            "isEntity": true,
            "label": "Calendar",
            "singular": "To Do"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Leads",
            "isEntity": true,
            "label": "Leads",
            "singular": "Lead"
        },
 ]
}
}
```

**Activity.java:**

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    LoginModules loginModules = response.body();
    String success = loginModules.getSuccess()
        .toString();
    if (success.equals("true")) {
        String result = loginModules.getResult()
            .toString();
        Log.i("result", ":" + result);
        String Userid = loginModules.getResult()
            .getUserid();
        Log.i("Userid", ":" + Userid);
        String Session = loginModules.getResult()
            .getSession();
        Log.i("Session", ":" + Session);
        String Vtiger_version = loginModules.getResult()
            .getVtiger_version();
        Log.i("Vtiger_version", ":" + Vtiger_version);
        String Mobile_module_version = loginModules.getResult()
            .getMobile_module_version();
        Log.i("Mobile_module_version", ":" + Mobile_module_version);
        //List<Modules> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        //Gson gson = new Gson();
        JSONArray jsonarray = null;
        try {
            jsonarray = new JSONArray("modules");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonobject = null;
            try {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = jsonobject.getString("id");
                Log.i("id", ":" + id);
                // String url = jsonobject.getString("url");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (username.equals("admin") && pass.equals("Password!1")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Username and Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's  the is problem ?

Comment: success should come true

Comment: Why are you using `success` as a String ? It's a Boolean...

Comment: `Log.e("response",new Gson().toJson(response.body()));` use this to find your problem.

Comment: @frankenstein {"success":"false"}

Comment: @jyothigen  you are getting data it mean something wrong with credential   or ` Api`.

Comment: @frankenstein see i have edited the code

Comment: @jyothigen your `result` is a class not an array.Try this api in `POSTMAN` .

Comment: http://gixworks.github.io/vtiger-mobile-client-ios/#loginAndFetchModules I am flowing this link

Comment: {
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "code": "INVALID_AUTH_TOKEN",
        "message": "Specified token is invalid or expired"
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Some data is missing in your model structure for parsing data.

```
"result": {
"login": {
    "userid": "1",
    "session": "fa000f0a6c5a414e62dcc4cbf99175d6",
    "vtiger_version": "5.2.0",
    "mobile_module_version": "1.2.1"
},
```

there is a "login" jsonobject in your "result" object. But you missed the "login" element when you parse it. you should create a java class as LoginModel.

```
 public class LoginModel {

            @SerializedName("session")
            @Expose
            private String session;
            @SerializedName("userid")
            @Expose
            private String userid;
            @SerializedName("vtiger_version")
            @Expose
            private String vtiger_version;
```

and put login model in your GetModuleList class.

```
public class GetLoginModuleList {

            @SerializedName("login")
            @Expose
            private LoginModel login;
```